# Problems with making multiprocessing infinity loop

Tags: python, multithreading, process, multiprocessing

**Purpose:** I've to check specific dir for new folder every second. And if there are new folder, I've to  do some work ( call another function ). And I'm trying to get loop work it continuously.

**Example: ** I've got 2 folders in 1 second, then I call check(folder_name : str) function. In the next second I'll got 5 folders, but my loop will not call check() because of previous check() function is still running.

**Code :**

```
def check(folder_name):
    #do some work

def scan():
    #checking if new folders in dir
    folder = sorted(os.listdir(main_path))
    while True:
        folder_ = sorted(os.listdir(main_path))

        if (len(folder_) > len(folder)):
            res = [x for x in folder + folder_ if x not in folder or x not in folder_]
            # if new folders when i starting new process to check folder in parallel
            p = Pool(processes=len(res))
            p.map(check, res)
            folder = folder_

        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   loop = Process(target=scan)
   loop.start()
   print('LOADED')`
```

Also, I've tried to create a process of main loop - scan(), then creating threads inside but it won't work

Comment: The problem in your code is that you are not updating the `folder` variable in the main process, so it will always compare the same number of folders, and the process will never start again. You should use a queue as a channel to communicate between the main process and the worker processes.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand you but I updating `folder` inside the `if (len(folder_) > len(folder))`. Also I tried to use `multiprocessing.Queue()` as solution for my problem and thats didn't work.

Comment: I don't see how a previous call to `check` can be in effect since you are using method `multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map`, which blocks until all submitted tasks complete.

Comment: Of course, if you find there is more than one new folder, you will be calling `check` in parallel, once for each new folder. Is there something about `check` that prevents it from successfully running in parallel?

Comment: In `check` I'm using selenium chromedriver to do some stuff and it works OK. My goal is to make loop wont stop.  Now it works like: finding new folders -> `check()` started and looping stopped -> `check()` is done and THEN loop starts. I have an idea, what if I will make `threads` but not `processes`. But I'm not sure if that will work. Also thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer: Use a call to `map_async` instead of `map` since the former will not block. But you should still allocate your pool once prior to your `while True:` loop using a reasonable maximum pool size.

**TL;DR**

Question: You have `res = [x for x in folder + folder_ if x not in folder or x not in folder_]`. This only makes sense if a folder can be deleted and you still want to process a deleted folder. Is that you really mean? For the purpose of this answer I am assuming you only want to process new folders that did not exist the previous time you checked. But I have code to handle your case also.

First, your call to `p.map` is a *blocking* call and that prevents you from checking for new folders until the previous task submissions complete. This is what I would do:

For efficiency sake I would create a pool *once* prior to the `while True:` loop instead of creating over and over again new process pools. This will require you to determine what the appropriate pool size should be (how many concurrent `selenium` processes do you really want to be running concurrently?). I would also question whether this should even be a multiprocessing pool. If your `check` function is mostly doing `selenium` screen scraping with relatively little CPU processing, it would be more efficient to use a multithreading pool since `selenium` is already being launched as a separate process.

You should also reuse these `selenium` processes for each submitted folder to be processed instead of repeatedly creating and quitting new `selenium` processes. To accomplish this each pool process can initialize "thread local" storage with a reference to a special `Driver` class instance that holds a reference to the actual `selenium` driver and will "quit" the `selenium` driver when the instance's "destructor" method (i.e. `__del__` method) is called, which will occur automatically when thread local storage is terminated within each pool process/thread. This is assuming you have some mechanism for eventually terminating the `scan` process.

```py
from multiprocessing import Process, Pool, Event
import threading
import time

class Driver:
    """
    This is a mechanism to automatically "quit" the driver
    when the pool terminates:
    """
    
    def __init__(self):
        # Using Chrome just as an example:
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument("--headless") # specify appropriate options
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

    def __del__(self):
        self.driver.quit() # clean up driver when we are cleaned up
        
    @staticmethod
    def get_driver():
        the_driver = getattr(threadLocal, 'the_driver', None)
        if the_driver is None:
            the_driver = Driver()
            setattr(threadLocal, 'the_driver', the_driver)
        return the_driver.driver
        
    @staticmethod
    def quit_driver():
        """
        Use this method to explicitly quit the driver
        instead of calling quit on the driver returned by get_driver().
        A new driver will be created when get_driver is called.

        Note: This method should not be required because the drivers will
        automatically be terminated when the pool closes. If you do need to
        repeatedly create and quit your driver for each submitted folder for some reason,
        then you should probably not be using this class and thread local
        storage at all.
        """
        setattr(threadLocal, 'the_driver', None) # This result in quit being called on the driver

def init_pool():
    """
    Create thread local storage for this pool process/thread:
    """
    
    global threadLocal
    
    threadLocal = threading.local()


def check(folder):
    driver = Driver.get_driver()
    #do some work
    ...

def scan(quit_event):
    #checking if new folders in dir
    # Use a set to simplify calculations:
    folder_set = set(os.listdir(main_path))
    # Create a "maximal" pool size
    MAX_PROCESSES = 20
    pool = Pool(MAX_PROCESSES, initializer=init_pool)
    while True:
        # Is there some condition that causes a break out
        # of this loop? How about an event?
        if quit_event.is_set():
            break
        updated_folder_set = set(os.listdir(main_path))
        folders_to_process_set = updated_folder_set - folder_set
        # Or the following to process also deleted folders:
        # folders_to_process_set = folder_set ^ updated_folder_set
        if folders_to_process_set:
            # Non blocking:
            pool.map_async(check, updated_folder_set)
            folder_set = new_folder_set
        time.sleep(1)

    # Wait for all submitted tasks to complete.
    # When the pool is terminated, all the selenium processes will
    # automatically be terminated.
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    quit_event = Event()
    scan_loop = Process(target=scan, args=(quit_event,))
    scan_loop.start()
    print('LOADED')
    ...
    quit_event.set()
    scan_loop.join()
```

Comment: Thank you Booboo, but I already figured it out! Good work man, appreciate that!

Comment: Also: I thought that creating and calling a specific func for scanning folder worthless since its `while True:` so i put in in main process. Anyway great job!